# Does one-way binding imply there are no watchers using a setTimeout function?

Tags: two-way-binding, ajax-polling

From what I am reading, two-way binding means there are "watchers" that implement a setTimeout in JavaScript every so many milliseconds to keep the model and view inline with each other.

In one-way binding, once the view is populated, are the events that are assigned to  an element what triggers syncing between model and view, thus no "watchers"?  My reason for asking is I do not believe using "watchers" is wise, but this will help me verify.  The browsers JS event loop seems to be sufficient for events.

(Please assume Angular, React, and Vue, if it is necessary to answer the question.)

I have read this,
[One-Way or One-Time binding in Angular and Watchers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34070986/one-way-or-one-time-binding-in-angular-and-watchers)